# Query Redshift cluster on AWS receiving error "Failed to connect to query service."

Tags: amazon-redshift, failed-to-connect

I created a redshift cluster and populated some sample tables inside. All works fine. I switched to another cluster (empty) and tried to switch back to the first one.

I was asked to enter the password which I am sure it is correct because I just logged 30 mins ago. But this time, it says "Failed to connect to query service." When I click on "Connect with temporary password". I got exactly the same message.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znbe2.jpg)

I am very puzzled, as what could have caused that? And I can't find this exact error message anywhere.

Any idea? Thank you very much! Ming

Comment: Do you have enhanced VPC routing enabled for your Redshift cluster? You cannot use query editor with Enhanced VPC routing. More details here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/query-editor.html#query-editor-considerations

Comment: Thanks for the link Tushar. The strange thing is that NOT only I was able to connect before and suddenly I couldn't connect anymore, but also we couldn't connect with workbench nor the data virtualization tool we are using anymore.